# Git Push commit via SSH fails in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-2017

I am new to git and trying to make it ready for my dev-project. I have a Disk-Station where my Remote-Repo is located and I communicate over SSH. I´ve read, that cloning over ssh fails in Visual Studio 2017 (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#a-idkiteamexplorer-ateam-explorer-issues), but pushing is not mentioned on that site. They say, that one can workaround the cloning-issue, by cloning with command line.

I´ve done that, and I am able to work with and commit the cloned content in Visual Studio. But if I try to push in my Team Explorer, I get the following message in my output-window:

> Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

If I push the content via command-line, it works. But that is not as handy as it can (should) be.
My Remote-URL looks like `ssh://<user>@<server>/Repos/Test`. I´ve read about some issues with denied access or something like that, but I think that is not my problem, as I didn´t recieved any access- or rights-related messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t really know if I just didn´t see it, or if someone from MS/VS changed something during the weekend, but if I try to publish it now, the following message occurs:
[image: Message from Teamexplorer]

I think, this question is answered with this message at the moment.