# Connection to Git server via Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-2017

I have an existing git server based on debian and want to use this as a repository for Visual Studio projects/solutions via SSH.
(I don't want to use VSTS, TFS or any cloud based services)

Currently I'm stuck at the point where I want to connect to the server:

I am using Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.4.1)

I tried to connect in several differnt ways via the Visual Studio Team Explorer, 
e.g.:

- added the ssh url **ssh://git:MYPASS@MYSERVER:9418/var/git/MYPROJECT**
  under Settings >> Repository Settings >> Remotes
- set it under Push >> Push To Remote Repository >> Publish Git Repo

But when I try to synch something I get the error message

> "Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Git
>   failed with a fatal error. fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository."

I guess the repository itself seems to work.
I have created a git repository on the servers project path with:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "inital commit"
```

and then I am able to clone it:

```
# git clone ssh://git@MYSERVER:9418/var/git/MYPROJECT
Cloning into 'MYPROJECT'...
The authenticity of host 'MYSERVER (192.168.x.x)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:1xkE0NAv6iP95ALYbS6ztirlCQiKGkCzYvNdrLUjopc.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'MYSERVER,192.168.x.x' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@MYSERVER's password:
remote: Zähle Objekte: 605, Fertig.
remote: Komprimiere Objekte: 100% (594/594), Fertig.
remote: Total 605 (delta 141), reused 0 (delta 0) eceiving objects:  99% (599/605)
Receiving objects: 100% (605/605), 1.66 MiB | 7.26 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (141/141), done.
```

There is another question: 
[Git Push commit via SSH fails in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43519508/git-push-commit-via-ssh-fails-in-visual-studio-2017) 
that comes to the conclusion that Visual Studio reports: "The SSH protocol is not currently supported"
But I have read other comments from the internet and I think meanwhile it is supported.

Since I am new to developing with git, I am grateful for any given hint!
Can you tell me what is wrong here and what I have to do to get my git server integrated in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to this:
I specified the ssh-url with a port and a password:

> ssh://git:MYPASS@MYSERVER:9418/var/git/MYPROJECT

but seemingly it should be without the port and without a password:

> ssh://git@MYSERVER/var/git/MYPROJECT

.. then it worked for me!

Comment: Hello... where do you configure the remote repository? I done it in GitHub settings screen, but it seems it is only intended to be used with GitHub. On the other hand, it also allows TFS, but what if I have other GIT repository?